# How to zooming whole gallery?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I try to display images with gallery view and it works fine, now I would like to add a zoom but the WHOLE gallery, not selected image.

The point is that all images are expanded and increased spacing between them.

How to do it?

Comment: What is the purpose of such a gallery? u can keep it simple and just zoom single image at a user requested time...

Comment: several pages of publication, displayed three pages at a time and when he zooming, all images expand and move away from each other in order not to impose - that I want

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you plan to do it, but if you just simply change all the candidate image size, the space among them would get bigger proportionally.

You can try setup the style of each frame in the gallery view. Steps are like:
1. override the gallery adapter, implement the getView funciton.
2. for imageView,  setLayoutParams,  setScaleType, both of which can be reference in the imageView doc, read the doc and adjust the params.

Answer (score 0):

Put images into [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). Actually make html page referencing your local images, put it into `<table`> element, and let WebView provide zooming. This will be fast, hw-accelerated, and will zoom as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be good solution to change size of Gallery widget from code as well as space between images, according to zoom level, so it fits to your needs?